# Android app to extract uncommon area between 2 images

Tags: android

Just opposite of what [Shoot & more (Erase Mode)](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/samsung-galaxy-s-5-guides/how-to-use-shot-more-for-drama-shots-eraser-and-more-on-the-galaxy-s-5/) do to remove unwanted object between 2 images, is there any app which can extract uncommon area of two images.
Or rather an app which can remove background automatically from an image by comparing 2nd image of background.

Or an image which spot the image difference to remove background image and result with transparent PNG.

Comment: I don't edit photos on my Android device, but have compiled a list of [Mini-Photoshops and Mini-Gimps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit#group_219) you might wish to take a look at. One of those should have that feature, hopefully.

Comment: oh!! its a huge list

Comment: And not the only one on that site :) As wherever possible links with reviews etc. are attached to the apps, this should make it easier to find the one you're looking for. At least that's the idea behind it ;)